# PHP mysql_query() cannot query sql requested

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

This is my `SQL` statement:

```
UPDATE approved_student SET barcode='11',phone='11',table_name='2',remark='' WHERE
studentid='5230010'; UPDATE approved_student SET 
barcode='22',phone='22',table_name='2',remark='' WHERE studentid='5230009';
```

Executing the `SQL` using `PHP` is not resulting in the desired outcome.

`PHP` source:

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","1234"); //connect database
mysql_select_db("lasto");//select name of the database

if($sql=mysql_query($data1)){
    echo 1;
}else{
    echo $data1;
}

mysql_close();
```

I sent the `SQL` using `POST`, but it does not work.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: HERE IS MY ANSWER!


$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","1234","lasto"); //connect database
//mysqli_select_db($con,"lasto");//select name of the database

if($mysqli->multi_query($data1)){
    echo 1;
}else{
    echo $data1;
}

$mysqli->close();

Answer (score 6):

You can only execute one commands at the time with mysql_query(), you should look at using mysqli or PDO instead.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE approved_student SET barcode='11',phone='11',table_name='2',remark='' WHERE
studentid='5230010'"); 

...

mysql_query("UPDATE approved_student SET 
barcode='22',phone='22',table_name='2',remark='' WHERE studentid='5230009'");
```

Comment: you mean that mysqli or PDO can execute at the same time right ?

Comment: @JongzPuangput Yeah that shouldn't be a problem.